# How to focus on tab, on notification click in Angular 8?

Tags: javascript, angular, push-notification, service-worker

The goal is that when a user clicks on the browser notification, to look if the page is already open and go to it, and if not, open it in a new tab or window.

this is doable when using the native service worker using this code

```
    const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
     type: 'window',
     includeUncontrolled: true   })   .then((windowClients) => {
     let matchingClient = null;

     for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
       const windowClient = windowClients[i];
       if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
         matchingClient = windowClient;
         break;
       }
     }

     if (matchingClient) {
       return matchingClient.focus();
     } else {
       return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
     }   });

   event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
```

but in angular they have their own service worker wrapper, and it generates service worker file on run time.

my code in angular now is this

```
  this.swPush.notificationClicks.subscribe(
    ({ action, notification }) => {
      if (notification && notification !== null && notification['data']) {
        const url = notification['data'].url;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
      }
    });
```

So first is there a way to implement this in angular (swPush) ?

if no, do I have to edit the generated service worker file, and how (best practice) ? 
or can I import another service worker file ?